E_UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS Error with AdonisJs and Google oAuth
I created a project with adonisjs by setting up google oAuth authentication. When I launch a call via postman on a route protected by my auth_middleware, I get the error 401 E_UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS
authRoutes :
const AuthController = () => import('#controllers/auth_controller')
import router from '@adonisjs/core/services/router'

export default function authRoutes() {
  router
    .group(() => {
      router.get('/login', [AuthController, 'login'])
      router.get('/callback', [AuthController, 'callback'])
    })
    .prefix('/auth/google')
}

auth_Controller :
import User from '#models/user'
import { HttpContext } from '@adonisjs/core/http'

export default class AuthController {
  async login({ ally }: HttpContext): Promise<any> {
    return ally.use('google').redirect()
  }

  async callback({ ally, session, auth, response }: HttpContext) {
    try {
      const googleUser = await ally.use('google').user()

      const user = await User.firstOrCreate(
        { googleId: googleUser.id },
        {
          email: googleUser.email,
          name: googleUser.name,
          avatar: googleUser.avatarUrl,
          accessToken: googleUser.token.idToken,
          refreshToken: googleUser.token.refreshToken,
        }
      )

      await auth.use('web').login(user)
      session.put('userId', user.id)

      session.flash('success', 'Connecter avec google')

      return response.redirect('/')
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('OAuth Error:', error)
    }
  }
}

auth_middleware :
import { Authenticators } from '@adonisjs/auth/types'
import { HttpContext } from '@adonisjs/core/http'
import { NextFn } from '@adonisjs/core/types/http'

export default class AuthMiddleware {
  /**
   * The URL to redirect to, when authentication fails
   */

  redirectTo = '/auth/google/login'

  async handle(
    ctx: HttpContext,
    next: NextFn,
    options: { guards?: (keyof Authenticators)[] } = {}
  ) {
    try {

      const guards = options.guards || ['web']

      // Authentification explicite
      await ctx.auth.authenticateUsing(guards, {
        loginRoute: this.redirectTo,
      })

      const isAuthenticated = await ctx.auth.check()

      if (!isAuthenticated) {
        return ctx.response.status(401).send('Unauthorized')
      }

      return next()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Authentication Error:', error)
      return ctx.response.redirect(this.redirectTo)
    }
  }
}

userModel : 

import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
import hash from '@adonisjs/core/services/hash'
import { compose } from '@adonisjs/core/helpers'
import { BaseModel, column, hasMany } from '@adonisjs/lucid/orm'
import { withAuthFinder } from '@adonisjs/auth/mixins/lucid'
import { DbAccessTokensProvider } from '@adonisjs/auth/access_tokens'
import Rooms from './rooms.js'
import type { HasMany } from '@adonisjs/lucid/types/relations'
import Guests from './guests.js'

const AuthFinder = withAuthFinder(() => hash.use('scrypt'), {
  uids: ['email'],
  passwordColumnName: 'password',
})

export default class User extends compose(BaseModel, AuthFinder) {
  @column({ isPrimary: true })
  public id!: number

  @column()
  public googleId!: string

  @column()
  public email!: string

  @column()
  public name?: string | null

  @column()
  public avatar?: string | null

  @column()
  public accessToken?: string | null

  @column()
  public refreshToken?: string | null

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true })
  public createdAt!: DateTime

  @column.dateTime({ autoUpdate: true })
  public updatedAt!: DateTime

  @hasMany(() => Rooms)
  public rooms!: HasMany<typeof Rooms>

  @hasMany(() => Guests)
  public guests!: HasMany<typeof Guests>

  static accessTokens = DbAccessTokensProvider.forModel(User)
}

auth :

import { defineConfig } from '@adonisjs/auth'
import { sessionGuard, sessionUserProvider } from '@adonisjs/auth/session'
import type { InferAuthEvents, Authenticators } from '@adonisjs/auth/types'

const authConfig = defineConfig({
  default: 'web',
  guards: {
    web: sessionGuard({
      useRememberMeTokens: false,
      provider: sessionUserProvider({
        model: () => import('#models/user'),
      }),
    }),
  },
})

export default authConfig

/**
 * Inferring types from the configured auth
 * guards.
 */
declare module '@adonisjs/auth/types' {
  export interface Authenticators extends InferAuthenticators<typeof authConfig> {}
}
declare module '@adonisjs/core/types' {
  interface EventsList extends InferAuthEvents<Authenticators> {}
}

session :
import env from '#start/env'
import { defineConfig, stores } from '@adonisjs/session'

const sessionConfig = defineConfig({
  enabled: true,
  cookieName: 'adonis-session',

  /**
   * When set to true, the session id cookie will be deleted
   * once the user closes the browser.
   */
  clearWithBrowser: false,

  /**
   * Define how long to keep the session data alive without
   * any activity.
   */
  age: '2h',

  /**
   * Configuration for session cookie and the
   * cookie store
   */
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false,
    sameSite: false,
  },

  /**
   * The store to use. Make sure to validate the environment
   * variable in order to infer the store name without any
   * errors.
   */
  store: env.get('SESSION_DRIVER'),

  /**
   * List of configured stores. Refer documentation to see
   * list of available stores and their config.
   */
  stores: {
    cookie: stores.cookie(),
  },
})

export default sessionConfig

In my local tests, the value of  const isAuthenticated = await ctx.auth.check()  is empty. I have configured the token on postman correctly, it matches the one stored in access_token in my user table.
